# How are Hibernate 6 custom validator messages displayed from a properties file?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I am attempting to get a custom error message display from a properties file. Although I am reading through the online guide for Hibernate 6 carefully, and the validator does work, the example they provide does not show a custom error. I have tried renaming the class in the properties file to 'Car' instead of 'car' and have tried different error classes such as Min or Max, but the default error messages will always be displayed. I suspect some issue with the format or naming of the properties file, but I don't know how it should be formatted.
Main Class:

```
package fieldConstraints;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator;
import org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator;

import methodParameterConstraints.RentalStation;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //An instance of validator is created, with the custom message resource included
    Validator validator = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure()
            .messageInterpolator(
                    new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(new PlatformResourceBundleLocator("MyMessages.properties")))
            .buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    Car Accord = new Car();
    //A null value is applied to the licensePlate variable
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> violations = validator.validateValue(
            Car.class,
           "licensePlate",
           null
    );
    //When getting the error message it will still display the default.
    for(ConstraintViolation<Car> violation : violations){
       System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
 }
    System.out.println(Accord.toString());
}
```

}

Car class:

```
 package fieldConstraints;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
 import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
 import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Car {
//For this class, the basic class variables are annotated with     constraints so that when 
//an instance is created , it must abide by these parameters.
@NotNull
private String manufacturer;

public Car() {
    //default constructor
}

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 14)
//Constraints can be applied to fields of any access type (public, private etc.). Constraints on static fields are not supported, though.
private String licensePlate;

@Min(2)
@Max(6)
private int seatCount;

public Car(String manufacturer, String licencePlate, int seatCount) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.licensePlate = licencePlate;
    this.seatCount = seatCount;
}
//Contructors, getters setters...
}
```

MyMessages.properties file:

```
Size.car.licensePlate = custom message here.
Min.car.seatCount = custom message: min 2 seats.
Max.car.seatCount  = custom message: max 6 seats.
NotNull.car.manufacturer = custom message: manufacturer can't be null.
```

Project file setup in Eclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To set a custom message in hibernate, try using the 'message' field in the annotation.

For Example:

```
@NotNull(message = "licensePlate cannot be null."
@Size(min = 2, max = 14, message = "Size of licensePlate needs to be between 2 and 14.")
private String licensePlate;
```

Comment: Yes this is an option, but I was trying to replicate the Hibernate 6.0 documentation's way of pulling the messages from one central file. Lets say you had to change an app over to Spanish from English, and you wanted to just point to a new file rather than retype every error message.